# How to run set.seed() generator only on one sample?

Tags: r

So I need to generate two samples. First with numbers 1:20 and second with letters. Also I need to impose set.seed(444) random generator but only on first sample with numbers, the second one should not use it. How can I use set.seed() only for the first one and avoid affecting my second sample by it?

```
set.seed(444)
x <-sample(1:20, 20, replace = F)  ## this one with set.seed()
y <-sample(letters, 20, replace=F) ## this one without set.seed()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `set.seed` with `NULL`

```
set.seed(444)
x <-sample(1:20, 20, replace = F) 
set.seed(NULL)
y <-sample(letters, 20, replace=F)
```